# Is it easier to expand or compress a rubber

Tags: elasticity

I know that rubber follow's Hook's law to a certain limit. So during this period is it easier to push or pull?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically, if we go through the formula of bluk modulus both forces came to be same for a partucular expansion of compression.

But if we see, for compressing you have to apply force at the both end is only normal force perpendicular to the end of face of rubber. But if you expand it you have to hold it and apply normal at the top of surface and then apply force in direction parralel to the length of the rubber which is nothing but fricition.

So, let $\mu$ be the fricition coefficient of rubber surface and you applied normal $N_1$ in compressing and $N_2$ in expanding. So,

And,$F$ be the force needed for change in volume of $V$,

$$F=N_1=\mu N_2$$

Generally the $\mu$ of upper surface will be less that unity. So,

$$\frac{N_1}{N_2}<1 ⟹ N_1<N_2$$

The thing is to note is the force applied by you isn't only $N_2$ in second case. It is,

$$\sqrt{N_2^2+\mu^2 N_2^2}$$.

Hence, you can see it will be easier to compress.